# Convert PHP timezone to something understandable by users?

Tags: php, timezone

I have a timezone stored in my database in proper PHP format with: "**America/New_York**"

The problem is, if I echo the timezone out back to the user, they see "America/New_York" and they may think thats a location, instead of a timezone. If the location is in New Jersey, or even in Florida, that could confuse people.

Is there an easy way to convert this timezone "America/New_York" to something more understandable by my users, such as "EST"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Check **T** and **Z** flags.

Comment: Not a great solution; timezone abbreviations are ambiguous, offsets even more. Perhaps a link to some site that would explain the timezone would be better.

Comment: From that information, anyone can explain the timezone. It's not that ambiguous as long as you know how to work with it :)